# gdb + arm debugger unable to trigger into FIQ in linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, arm, embedded-linux, interrupt

I'm having difficulties getting debugger and `gdb` to work as expected with a FIQ handler in Linux kernel. It can trigger fine to the driver code that sets up the condition for FIQ triggering, but not with FIQ.

I'm using `ARM-USB-TINY-H` debugger + `imx233-SJTAG` converter (the board doesn't have pins for parallel JTAG) from Olimex to debug i.mx233 board.

I'm compiling `gdb 7.5.1` with buildroot, and `openocd 0.6.1` comes from Ubuntu repository. I launch openocd:

```
# openocd -f olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg -f imx233.cfg

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.6.1 (2012-12-06-17:15)
....
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
trst_and_srst srst_pulls_trst srst_gates_jtag trst_push_pull srst_open_drain
adapter speed: 800 kHz
dcc downloads are enabled
fast memory access is enabled
Info : max TCK change to: 30000 kHz
Info : clock speed 789 kHz
Info : JTAG tap: imx23.cpu tap/device found: 0x079264f3 (mfg: 0x279, part: 0x7926, ver: 0x0)
Info : Embedded ICE version 6
Info : imx23.cpu: hardware has 2 breakpoint/watchpoint units
```

Starting `gdb` and setting up the breakpoint:

```
# arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gdb vmlinux
....
target remote :3333
Remote debugging using :3333
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) monitor halt
target state: halted
target halted in ARM state due to debug-request, current mode: Supervisor
cpsr: 0x600000d3 pc: 0xc0019024
MMU: enabled, D-Cache: enabled, I-Cache: disabled
(gdb) hbreak mydriver_userland_write
Hardware assisted breakpoint 1 at 0xc02da930: file drivers/misc/mydriver.c, line 309.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Now at this point the gdb will happily trigger, when ever I send message from userland to the driver.

```
Breakpoint 1, mydriver_userland_write (filp=0xc2cb81c0, buf=0x19d8600 "1\n\235\001t", count=2, f_pos=0xc2cb3f88) at drivers/misc/mydriver.c:309
309                       size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
```

After processing the information from userland, I initialize the conditions for FIQ to trigger, and return.
In `gdb`, I setup the breakpoint for FIQ. (line 60 is basically 4th assembler instruction after clearing the interrupt flag)

```
## Enable catching for FIQ vectors
(gdb) monitor arm9 vector_catch fiq
reset: don't catch
undef: don't catch
swi: don't catch
pabt: don't catch
dabt: don't catch
irq: don't catch
fiq: catch

## setup the breakpoint
(gdb) hbreak myfiq_handler.S:60
Hardware assisted breakpoint 1 at 0xc02db040: file     drivers/misc/myfiq_handler.S, line 60.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Now after all is setup, I trigger the condition that results into FIQ processing, and this is where strange result happens:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0xffff001c in ?? ()
```

I can't do anything at this point really:

```
## Try to see call trace
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffff001c in ?? ()

## Try stepping
(gdb) step
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb) next
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

`monitor reg` shows register state like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/6113942/
If I look at the vmlinux map file, the PC points literylly last 4 lines of the file:

```
ffe5095d A __crc_groups_free
fff3672c A __crc_directly_mappable_cdev_bdi
ffffe9f5 A __crc_cfg80211_wext_giwfrag
     w __crc_softirq_work_list
```

If I use `stepi` command, the whole execution seems to hang.

I'm still learning how to use `gdb`, so I really have no clue where to look for the problem now.. any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *FIQ* routine is copied to the *tail end* of the vector table.  The layout of the **ARM** vector table is,

1. Reset
2. Undefined instruction
3. Software interrupt (SWI)
4. Pre-fetch abort
5. Data Abort
6. *4-byte hole*
7. IRQ (normal interrupt)
8. FIQ (fast interrupt).

As well as the banked registers `r8-r14`, the `FIQ` mode hands execution directly to address *0x1c* (plus table offset).  All of the other exceptions will typically do a branch instruction.  However, for the `FIQ`, there is no need to branch meaning that your assembler routine can execute directly.

See the routine `set_fiq_handler()` in Linux's [fiq.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/fiq.c).  Your **GDB** will be un-aware of this relocation and will place a break-point at the original address.  As a *caveat*, the initial `FIQ` routine must be **PC-relative** or it will not execute.  In **GDB**, you can use `b 0xffff001c` to set a break-point at the initial `FIQ` instruction.

Other exception and the vector table definition are in [entry-armv.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S) near the bottom of the file as `__vectors_start` with the `W(b) vector_fiq` instruction, which will be over-written by your routine.  See also [vmlinux.lds.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S) which is the *linker script* for the kernel.  You have a space of *0x1000-0x1c* as the size of the `FIQ` routine.

Comment: Actually, your code may get away with not being **PC-relative** as a copy of the code (and `.data`, `.rodata`) exists at the original address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply once again, artless noise. So, it makes me wonder then why debugger triggered then ? I mean I set the bp to `0xc02db040` initially.. Is it because I told **gdb** `monitor arm9 vector_catch fiq` ?
Sorry to bring another element to the same question, but if I set the bp to `0xffff001c`, can I still somehow make for example **ddd** show me the fiq code (from my myfiq_handler.S) and be able to visualize the progress better ?

Comment: For some reason, I'm still unable to step anymore after breakpoint.. 
I seem to run into `if (find_pc_partial_function (pc, &name,&tp->control.step_range_start,&tp->control.step_range_end) == 0)` in `gdb/infcmd.c` function `step_once`

Comment: I think that `gdb` is complaining that you are in code that it has no idea about; regarding the `find_pc_partial...`.  Your initial breakpoint may work as your code might jump back to the old point, or you have some other facility set that causes the break.  I would debug in a regular mode; I have never found a debugger productive for ISRs.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you comment if this approach makes any sense: If I would move my FIQ code to for example those userland communication functions (character device read/write functions) in the driver. Since I would like to access memory-mapped pointers to control GPIOs. If I would move this _fully_ to userland, I would have to re-map everything, and also I don't have gdb on the _board userland_

Comment: Also, should I save and restore register states in the function if I start write my FIQ handler in the middle of the function ? Is there some handy command that would automatically generate save/restore calls ? I'm thinking something like (in the function called by userland) 1) save register state 2) write the fiq block `asm volatile("mov r0, r0") etc` 3) restore state 4) return from function

Comment: You can setup the `fiq` registers and use a `/proc` or `/sys` write to call a function which switches to `fiq` mode in kernel space and executes the routine under test.  This should minimize the code differences when the `FIQ` is actually active.  Even though you debug the CPU, there is different hardware on the SOC that is not being serviced.  Some DMA hardware could do something abnormal for instance when you pause execution for a long time.  Use [fiqasm.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/fiqasm.S) as a template for switching modes.

Comment: This is very interesting idea! Currently I don't really worry if I would have to reset the board after "one execution cycle" of the routine, as I clearly still need to learn how to write properly working fiq routine. Looking at the `fiqasm.S` routine, it seems clear how to switch into `fiq` mode and back, but I don't yet underestand how the FIQ registers are set with those `ldmia` instructions. Though I suppose from the point of this exercise, it's not necessary anyway.